# Bound animation plays more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, propertychanged

I use a MVVM and i came to a situation where i need a button to trigger an animation.
So i set and EventTrigger for it and it runs this animation:

```
<DoubleAnimation 
    (...)
    From="{Binding ElementName=Browser, Path=DataContext.TooltipPosition}"
To="150"/>
```

The problem is that I don't want that animation to play more than once. So after first button press it should go from 0 to 150 and for all succeeding clicks it should not be visible, so it should go from 150 to 150.
In my ViewModel I have a property TooltipPosition which is set to 0. I created a command for my button that sets this property to 150 and calls.

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TooltipPosition").
```

The problem is that this property is changed after second click, so I can see this animation playing twice.

How can I fix that?

-edit-

Yeah, well sorry I didn't include all the information.
I am trying to animate a lot of objects with just one of them being visible. So if user changes selection of object in GUI then animation should start from 0 to 150 again. And obviously if element A was animated, then B, and then again A, then this animation wouldn't be visible.

-edit2-

I animate Width of TextBlock. The thing is I've got multiple (binding data) TextBlocks and only one or none of them should be visible at any time. So i bound Width property of every TextBlock and I animate so basically all of them are influenced by this animation. But only one of them may be visible so it does the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to include purely view-related-things like animations in your ViewModel. MVVM doesn't mean "no code in the code behind". It means that what is not purely view-related should be put in a ViewModel.
Personally, I may avoid using bindings in your particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

You could leave out the `From` value.

See the *Remarks* section in [DoubleAnimation.To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.to):

> The animation progresses from the animated property's base value or a previous animation's output value to the value specified by the To property

Comment: Yeah, well sorry I didn't include all the information. I am trying to animate a lot of objects with just one of them being visible. So if user changes selection of object in GUI then animation should start from 0 to 150 again. And obviously if element A was animated, then B, and then again A, then this animation wouldn't be visible.

Comment: What do you animate? If it's a property of your objects A and B, it should work with only setting the animation's `To` value.

Comment: I animate Width of TextBlock. The thing is I've got multiple (binding data) TextBlocks and only one or none of them should be visible at any time. So i bound Width property of every TextBlock and I animate so basically all of them are influenced by this animation. But only one of them may be visible so it does the trick.